# Directory name error when creating dir in python out of the blue

Tags: python, pandas, directory, filenames

So i am using a method i made to save some plots of data, and i have automated the process by saving the plots in a sub folder in my current working directory, that has the name of the first and last dates of the data i am doing the plots for.

I have been using said function normally with no problem except one folder (yes only one) with data, gives me an error related to the name of the directory being created as it being incorrect

> OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'C:\Users\tiger\Documents\Radiator_Test\valve_3_5\12.08.2022_21:00-12.12.2022_04:00_dir'

the string created to be used to make the dir is this:

> C:\Users\tiger\Documents\Radiator_Test\valve_3_5\12.08.2022_21:00-12.12.2022_04:00_dir

which i have already in the past made successfully files that have this name already and at the same time on other data folders i use the same method with the same format of the name and it works normally

[image: folder with already made directories that of the past, i add manually at the end of every subdirs name the averaging time i used just to be clear with the names are a little bit different]

the part of the code that is responsible for the directory creation is this:

```
first_date, last_date = hfc.help_func.first_last_date(data)

directory = os.getcwd()
directory = os.path.join(directory,first_date + '-' + last_date + '_' +  'dir')
isExist = os.path.exists(directory)
subdir = first_date + '-' + last_date + '_' +  'dir'
if not isExist:
    # Create a new directory because it does not exist
    os.makedirs(directory)
```

I have tried looking at other methods i use and work normally and they identical to this one that doesn't work. Mind you it used to work fine and randomly without changing that part of the code it doesn't

If more details are required or parts of the code please let me know I will provide them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using windows, then using `:` as part of the directory name is not valid, for example, when manually renaming a folder with `:` you would get:
[image]

Therefore, simply consider replacing the `:` values for `_` or `-` as you have been regularly doing.

Simply using this should suffice:

```
first_date, last_date = [x.replace(":","") for x in hfc.help_func.first_last_date(data)]
```

Comment: Thank you very much friend, i happen to use a different format of time for this set of data and it totally slipped my mind that the ":" character is not valid for naming things. Sorry for the dumb question and have a nice day :)